# R Passing string arguments (column names) into a function does not work?

Tags: r, function, select, arguments, multiple-columns

Basically, I want to extract the unique values of two columns "MAT_cat and Ndep_cat" of an existing dataframe and expand grid to create a new dataframe "cat_xy" with all the combinations of unique values.

I am trying this simple one-line code which works just fine outside a function (sorry I am a newbie, the code probably look ugly):
`cat_xy <-  expand.grid(data.frame(unique(na.omit(obs_data1[,"MAT_cat"])), unique(na.omit(obs_data1[,"Ndep_cat"]))))`

But it does not work inside a function (it prompts me to debug mode, stopping at "Called from: `[.data.table`(data, , group1)"):

`Func <- function(data, group1, group2) { cat_xy <-  expand.grid(data.frame(unique(na.omit(data[,group1])), unique(na.omit(data[,group2])))) }`

I pass `group1 and group2` as strings. Any advice? I have been trying to solve this for a long time but no avail.

I have spent an extremely long time searching for answers but it seems to be
a generic problem and hence does not have a lot of specific answers. I tried things like eval(parse(text = group1) and then rename the column headers (because it would inherit unique(na.omit(eval(parse(text = group1) as column names...). I find this solution very unclean and dislike it.

Comment: do you have a reproducible example of your data?

Comment: Your error says you are using the `data.table` package. Unlike base data frames, `dt[, "column"]` returns a data.table, not a vector. (tidyverse tibbles also work this way.)  Use `dt[["column"]]` to extract a vector from a data table. This will work with `data.frame`, `data.table` or `tibble` inputs.

Comment: So the body of your function should be `expand.grid(data.frame(unique(na.omit(data[[group1]])), unique(na.omit(data[[group2]])))) }`